# Sovled: Powershell - How to store arguments to a variable and use it?

Tags: powershell, arguments, texturepacker

I have written a CMD script for batching atlas packs, and it works fine.

## CMD Script

```
set OutputDir=%1
set MaxSize=%2
set Scale=%3

set TpCmd=--format unity-texture2d --smart-update --max-size %MaxSize% --scale %Scale%
TexturePacker %TpCmd% --data "%OutputDir%.tpsheet" --sheet "%OutputDir%.png" "D:\xxx"
```

.
.
Recently I am learning PowerShell and try to write a script that could works like above.

## PowerShell Script

```
$AtlasMaxSize = 4096
$AtlasScale = 0.5

function Pack-Atlas($FileName) {
    $AtlasOptions = --format unity-texture2d --smart-update --max-size $AtlasMaxSize --scale $AtlasScale
    TexturePacker $AtlasOptions --data "$FileName.tpsheet" --sheet "$FileName.png" "D:\xxx"
}
```

.
.
But it seems not a correct way for declaring the $AtlasOptions variable.
I think maybe need some way to store the options, could someone help me or provide some keywords?
.
.
.
.
.

## Update

Thanks for @gvee and @TobyU
I have edited the script.
.

```
function Pack-Atlas($FileName, $AtlasMaxSize, $AtlasScale) {
    $AtlasOptions = "--format unity-texture2d --smart-update --max-size $AtlasMaxSize --scale $AtlasScale"
    TexturePacker $AtlasOptions --data "$FileName.tpsheet" --sheet "$FileName.png" $TargetPath
}
```

But it seems not work.
That's the error message I got:

TexturePacker:: error: Unknown argument
--format unity-texture2d --smart-update --max-size 4096 --scale 0.5 - please check parameters or visit `http://www.codeandweb.com/texturepacker` for newer version

Comment: `$AtlasOptions = '--format', 'unity-texture2d', '--smart-update', '--max-size', $AtlasMaxSize, '--scale', $AtlasScale`

Comment: Thanks a lot, It works !!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to put the value of your variable within quotes like below to declare it properly:

```
$AtlasMaxSize = 4096
$AtlasScale = 0.5

function Pack-Atlas($FileName) {
    $AtlasOptions = "--format unity-texture2d --smart-update --max-size $global:AtlasMaxSize --scale $global:AtlasScale"
    TexturePacker "$AtlasOptions --data '$($FileName).tpsheet' --sheet '$($FileName).png' 'D:\xxx'"
}
```

This should always be done like that if your value is not a number.

Answer (score 0):

You need to extend your functions to have other parameters that you can pass in:

```
function Pack-Atlas ($FileName, $AtlasMaxSize, $AtlasScale) {
    $AtlasOptions = "--format unity-texture2d --smart-update --max-size $AtlasMaxSize --scale $AtlasScale"
    TexturePacker $AtlasOptions --data "$FileName.tpsheet" --sheet "$FileName.png" "D:\xxx"
}
```

You can then pass in the additional arguments:

```
Pack-Atlas -FileName "/temp/foo.bar" -AtlasMaxSize 4096 -AtlasScale 0.5
```